# Is it possible to pass "draft" option to documentclass with arara?

Tags: compiling, arara, draft

I have this document:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt, openright, 
%   draft
    ]{book}

\begin{document}
Something
\end{document}
```

If I want both the final version and the draft one, I have to run `arara` once, rename the output pdf, uncomment `draft`, and run `arara` again.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex { pass-this-option-to-documentclass : draft , call-the-doc : _draft}
\documentclass[11pt, openright, 
    ]{book}

\begin{document}
Something
\end{document}
```

And get both draft pdf and final one in one run?

Comment: As far as I know arara doesn't know about the concept of output files (how should it rename PDF output if it doesn't even know whether a PDF has been produced; note that pdflatex might produce a DVI etc.). And concerning input manipulation: It might be easier to use other tools. But as this is more of a feature request, you should open one at https://github.com/cereda/arara/issues.

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you! I imagined it wasn't possible. I'll try to do something with Nppexec.

Comment: @TeXnician sorry but why shouldn't it be possible to pass --jobname to pdflatex through a rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

arara can change the jobname. I made a copy of pdflatex.yaml called pdflatexX.yaml and changed it in two places, at the identifier:

```
identifier: pdflatexX
```

and at the draft rule (I don't think that it is useful anyway, I never use --draftmode):

```
- identifier: draft
  flag: >
    @{
        joboption='--jobname=';
        jobname=getBasename(file).concat('-draft');
        return joboption.concat(jobname)
     }
```

Passing the draft option could be done with some command line definitions but I prefer a bit expl3 code and simply test the jobname:

```
% arara: pdflatexX
% arara: pdflatexX: {draft: yes}

\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\str_if_in:NnT \jobname {draft} {\def\@classoptionslist{draft}}
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\documentclass[11pt, openright]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Something \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

this produces two pdf files -- one with `-draft` attached to the name which uses draft setting.

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. I use draft mode to create two versions of the document, one "public", one "for my eyes only", where I put some notes and comments.

Comment: But it should be done also for biber, etc...